# React Native FlatList Infinite Scroll with Caching - API Calls Triggered Unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, caching

**Description:**

I'm developing a React Native app that fetches images from the NASA API for Mars rovers. Each rover has its own set of images, and I'm implementing an infinite scroll to display these images. I'm facing an issue with caching and unnecessary API calls.

**Problem:**

When I first enter the screen, the app correctly fetches and displays the initial batch of 25 images from the NASA API. I've implemented caching using AsyncStorage to store these images, so they don't need to be fetched again when I leave and re-enter the screen.

However, the problem arises when I go back to the screen after leaving it. Instead of displaying the cached images and preventing new API calls, the app fetches the images again, causing unnecessary API calls and performance issues.

**Code Snippet:**

*Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:*

```
// ...imports

const PictureCollection = ({ route }: PictureCollectionStackParams) => {
  const { title } = route.params;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<Photo[]>([]);

  const handleFetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    axios
      .get(
        // API URL
      )
      .then(res => {
        .then(res => {
        if (res.data.photos.length === 0) {
          setLoadMore(false);
        }
        setResponse(prevResponse => [...prevResponse, ...newPhotos]);
        setIsLoading(false);

        // store new images in cache
        try {
          // Store new photos in cache
          AsyncStorage.setItem(
            `cachedPhotos_${title}`,
            JSON.stringify([...response, ...newPhotos]),
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error saving cached photos:', error);
        }
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        // Handling errors
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem(`cachedPhotos_${title}`)
        .then(cachedPhotos => {
          if (cachedPhotos) {
            setResponse(JSON.parse(cachedPhotos));
            console.log('Cached photos displayed');
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error loading cached photos:', error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading cached photos:', error);
    }
    handleFetchData();
  }, [currentPage, title]);

    const onEndReached = () => {
    if (loadMore && !isLoading) {
      setLoadMore(true);
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
      console.log('loading more items');
    }
  };

  // ...rest of the code
};

export default PictureCollection;
```

**Expected Result:**

1. First time entering the screen: Fetches and displays the initial 25 images from the NASA API. Caches these images using AsyncStorage.
2. Leave the screen and re-enter: Displays the cached images from the initial batch without making new API calls.
3. As the user scrolls down and reaches the end of the initially loaded images, the app should fetch additional images from the API and display them without duplicating the cached ones.
4. Only the first 25 pictures should be cached. =>  that was the next step but I'm already here asking, so let's do it complete.

**Actual Scenario:**

1. First Entry: Upon the initial entry to the screen, the app fetches images from the NASA API and correctly caches them using AsyncStorage.
2. Re-entry: Upon returning to the screen, the cached images are displayed as expected.
3. Issue Arises: However, after displaying the cached images, the app starts to trigger unnecessary API calls, causing performance problems.

Console Log Sequence:

1. LOG NASAnewOne 25 - Logged when entering the screen for the first time. Fetches 25 images.
2. LOG cachedPhotos displayed - Logged upon re-entry. Cached images are correctly displayed.
3. LOG NASAnewOne 25 - Starts triggering unnecessary API calls, fetching images again.
   ERROR Warning: Encountered two children with the same key... - Warning about duplicated keys in rendered components.

**Questions:**

1. What is triggering the API call in the second visit after the cached images are displayed?
2. How can I just cache the first batch of 25 el

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue maybe in useEffect, first code runs try catch( gets images from storage) and then still calls handleFetchData(). Try to add if statement to call handleFetchData() only if there are no cachedPhotos, add else after this code for example:

```
if (cachedPhotos) {
            setResponse(JSON.parse(cachedPhotos));
            console.log('Cached photos displayed');
          }
        })
```